# Llama2 returns multiple [INST] '''json {"action":, "action_input":} answers

Tags: python, prompt, llama

I have cloned [localGPT](https://github.com/PromtEngineer/localGPT) and switched to YanaS/llama-2-7b-langchain-chat-GGUF from HuggingFace. The model returns multiple answers instead of just one:

````
Question:
{{question}}

Answer:
 ```json
{"action": "Final Answer", "action_input": {{answer1}}}
``` [INST] {{somehow rephrased question}} [/INST] ```json
{"action": "Final Answer", "action_input": {{answer2}}}
``` [INST] {{somehow rephrased question again}} [/INST] ```json
{"action": "Final Answer", "action_input": {{yet another answer}}} and so on.
````

I have no idea why this happens and how to fix it. because in the code the output is presented this way:

```
    while True:
    query = input("\nEnter a query: ")
    if query == "exit":
        break
    # Get the answer from the chain
    res = qa(query)
    answer, docs = res["result"], res["source_documents"]

    # Print the result
    print("\n\n> Question:")
    print(query)
    print("\n> Answer:")
    print(answer)
```

I when I work with the default model I also get multiple answers like this.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: this is not linked to chatGPT or in any way generated with chatGPT. just the repo is called localGPT. I use llama2 and I need help with it.

Comment: This doesn't change the fact that its generative AI, and we have no way of telling why it is hallucinating the answer it does.